# I am having trouble populating an array using InputBox

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having trouble populating an array using `InputBox`.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int array;
    int num;

    string value = Interaction.InputBox("Enter Array size","Enter Array size");
    if (int.TryParse(value, out array))
    {
        int[] Size = new int[array];

        txtOutput.Text = "Numbers: " + "\r\n";

        foreach (int i in Size)
        {
            string prompt = Interaction.InputBox("Enter values" + (i+1), "Enter values");
            if(int.TryParse(prompt, out num))

            txtOutput.Text += i + "\t";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: each time I enter a value (number), it displays a 0!!

Comment: Display "num" instead.  You'd better put it in the array as well.  Using foreach is nonsense, you are iterating elements of the array that are not yet set.  Which is what got you into trouble, use a plain for(;;) loop.

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop. With foreach you are going by the contents.

Comment: I used 'num' instead of 'i' with 'txtOutput.Text' and it's working perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string value = Interaction.InputBox("Enter Array size", "Enter Array size");
int array = 0;
if (int.TryParse(value, out array))
{
    int[] size = new int[array];
    txtOutput.Text = "Numbers: " + "\r\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)
    {
        string prompt = Interaction.InputBox("Enter values" + (i + 1), "Enter values");
        int num = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(prompt, out num))
        {
            size[i] = num;
            txtOutput.Text += size[i] + "\t";
        }
    }
}
```